# Why do I see a blank screen after form submission in PHP?

Tags: php, mysql

For the life of me I can't find what's wrong. It's just a search using the "num" field to pull from database and display all other row info for the corresponding number. Please help :/

```
<form action="search.php" method="post">
    Number :<input type="text" value="<?php if(isset($num)) echo $num;?>" name ="number"/> 
    <input type="submit" value="Search"/>
</form>
<?php
    if($_POST) 
    {
        $query = "SELECT * FROM r5s WHERE num = '$num'";
        $result = mysql_query($query) or die();
        $count=mysql_num_rows($result);

        if($count==0 & $num!="")
        {
            echo "The number is not found.<br/>Please try again with correct number.";
        }

        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) 
        {
?>
        <p class="title-table">Renter profile</p>
        <table class="view-result">
            <tr><td><span class="header-field">Name</span></td></tr>
            <tr><td><span class="result-field"><?php echo $row['name'];?></span></td></tr>

            <tr><td><span class="header-field">SSN</span></td></tr>
            <tr><td><span class="result-field"><?php echo $row['num'];?></span></td></tr>

            <tr><td><span class="header-field">DOB</span></td></tr>
            <tr><td><span class="result-field"><?php echo $row['birth'];?></span></td></tr>

            <tr><td><span class="header-field">Rating</span></td></tr>
            <tr><td><span class="result-field"><?php echo $row['rank'];?></span></td></tr>

            <tr><td><span class="header-field">History</span></td></tr>
            <tr><td><span class="result-field"><?php echo $row['hist'];?></span></td></tr>

            <tr><td><span class="header-field">Comments</span></td></tr>
            <tr><td><span class="result-field"><?php          enter code here`echo $row['comments'];?></span></td></tr>
        </table>
<?php
        }
        mysql_close($conn);
    }
?>
```

Comment: We can't help until you actually tell us what the problem is.

Comment: searches return no response or blank screen and wrong numbers submitted do not result in error just same non response.

Comment: `$query = "SELECT * FROM r5s WHERE num = '" . $num . "'";` to fix this.

Comment: `mysql_query($query) or die();` will cause a blank screen with no info about what went wrong. Use `mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());` to get an error message from the database... but note that the `mysql` library is outdated, and people learning the ropes should get started with mysqli or PDO straight away.

Comment: Another thing which could be at play, is your `if($_POST)`. Try using `if(isset($_POST['submit'])){` then name your submit button like so `<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Search"/>` --- May not completely solve your problem but that `if($_POST)` is not always a reliable method.

Comment: @DevlshOne Why do you think that will help? What's wrong with string interpolation?

Comment: Where do you set the variable `$num`? Are you missing `$num = $_POST['number'];`?

Comment: Another error in your code `if($count==0 & $num!="")` should be `if($count==0 && $num!="")`, change & to &&

Comment: now im getting error "Table 'comdevrentfriend.r5s' doesn't exist"

Comment: comdevrentfriend is the database name and r5s is table i'm referencing

Comment: Using the deprecated extension mysql instead of mysqli is A mistake.

Comment: or PDO for mysql and using prepared statements instead of allowing SQL injections (hint: if `$num` is user input, they can make it `'; drop database comdevrentfriend; 'lol` and now your database is gone). http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php and http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php for imminent learning.

Comment: I'm adding an escapestring before making it live. Could anyone please tell me what this error means and how to fix it?

Comment: Where is the portion of code you connect to the database? are your perhaps forgetting to call [**`mysql_select_db`**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-select-db.php)? to select the database the table is at? Have you double-checked if the database name and table name are correct? This is also wrong `<?php          enter code here`echo $row['comments'];?>` and should break your code.

Comment: prix -<?php
    $dbhost = "localhost";
    $dbuser = "root";
    $dbpassword = "xxxxxx";
    $dbdatabase = "comdevrentfriend";
    

    $conn = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpassword) or die();
    mysql_select_db($dbdatabase, $conn);
    
    //$conn = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser) or die();
    //mysql_select_db($dbdatabase, $conn);
    
   ?>

Comment: `now im getting error "Table 'comdevrentfriend.r5s' doesn't exist"` the error is pretty clear you should double check if the table is present on that database perhaps it was a different database you had that table created on.

Comment: As you can see you have mistyped the table name or you don't have the table named 'r5s'. If you're sure you do, then you're looking in the wrong db.

Comment: You should EDIT the question to include all the additional details.  A giant thread of comments in NOT very useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently, it sounds like your PHP is configured to not show any errors at all. The following will let you show errors for a particular folder in your website:

To do so, create a file named ".htaccess" in the same folder as your PHP file.

Make it's contents like this:

```
php_flag log_errors 1
php_value error_log /tmp/php_error.log (NOTE: This file has to exist and be writable)
php_flag session.use_trans_sid on
php_flag display_errors on
php_flag display_startup_errors on
php_flag magic_quotes_runtime on
php_value error_reporting 2047 or use value 497 for just errors (no notices or warnings)
php_flag magic_quotes_gpc off
php_flag register_globals off
php_value include_path .:/path/that/you/want/to/use
Options All -Indexes
```

Note that you'll want to be sure you can delete this file if required, as this can cause errors if your server doesn't support some of these features. So make a new directory, and put this .htaccess file in it. Then try and access a simple php file in that folder to see if it throws an error or not. If it doesn't, then it's fine to put in your real folder with your problem PHP file. Note that you need to change some file paths above to make it really work.

Comment: Simpler / faster to just add to the php script `ini_set('display_errors', '1');` and `error_reporting(E_ALL);`, don't you think? Don't have to jack with htaccess files.

Comment: if there's a fatal error, ini_set will not have any effect and PHP's configuration will have to be overridden

Comment: in my experience, this has been a good "copy in" and see it work solution. without changing code. if you think ini_set is better, just submit it as another answer! thanks! and this solution works globally for all sub folders. Your code based solution requires you editing either a core file, or a very simple scenario (ie one file)